# Why can't I see my accepted answers count?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I want to see my accepted answers count. Why isn't there any such option on Stack Overflow?

Even everyone should be able to see the number of each other.

Comment: The accept ratio used to be shown to all, but it was removed because users used it to force other users to accept more answers. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/204841

Comment: Wait, did you mean answers accepted by you or your answers that were accepted by others?

Comment: @ModusTollens yes I meant both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's trivial to do that using search:

[user:me isaccepted:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1)

If you want to search for such stats, it's easy to do so yourself, and since it's not used for any privileges or tag badges, I see no need to feature it prominently.